# How does objectproperty() figure out if a function is deterministic in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How does sql server determine if a function is deterministic or not?

Consider the following function, I think it's deterministic (as it's ultimately an integer operation), but sql server returns 0 when I call the objectproperty method on it.

Understanding how it works will help me understand why I'm wrong in my assessment of this function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EndOfPreviousMonth ( @Date date )
RETURNS date
AS BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(day, 0 - DAY(@Date), @Date);
END;

SELECT dbo.EndOfPreviousMonth('2010-01-01'); --Usage example

--Returns 0, I expected it to return 1
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID( 'dbo.EndOfPreviousMonth' ), 'IsDeterministic' );
```

Comment: Are you running in compatibility mode for anything?

(Ignore previous, `DATEADD` *is* deterministic.)

Comment: No, I don't think so. I guess that's to say I didn't set a compatibility mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First it looks whether used functions are [deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx).
Then it looks whether your function is schema bound.
(Or in reverse order.)

So add `with schemabinding` to your function.

Comment: That changed the answer to what I was expecting, but why?

Comment: @BrianDishaw I'm not sure, to be honest. Apparently because any data-accessing function is not deterministic unless schema bound, and SQL Server expands this behaviour to functions that don't in fact access data. Maybe it's not able to see they don't.

Comment: I don't understand it either. It would make more sense if I had something in the function that I could drop. Oh well, thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: Explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx)